# QStyledItemDelegate drawLine not working as supposed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a custom QStyledItemDelegate class for a QTableView. I would like to draw a line that divides the item in half. Like here:

[image: QLine]

However, the line is not painted in every item, but only in the first one.
However, if I draw a rectangle, it is painted in every item.

[image: QRect]

Working Example:

i did not manage to activate python syntaxt highlithing, sry about that.

```py
class CustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        rect = option.rect
        # render line
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("red")))
        painter.drawLine(QPoint(0, rect.height() // 2), QPoint(rect.width(), rect.height() // 2))

        # render rect
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("black")))
        rect.adjust(20, 20, -20, -20)
        painter.drawRect(rect)


class CustomTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create model
        model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                item = QStandardItem(f"Row {row}, Col {col}")
                model.setItem(row, col, item)

        # create delegate
        delegate = CustomDelegate()

        # set model
        self.setModel(model)

        # set delegate
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        # isntall event filter
        self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            print("Mouse moved over the widget at:", event.pos())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(window)

    custom_table_view = CustomTableView()
    layout.addWidget(custom_table_view)

    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Call `self.initStyleOption(option, index)` in  `paint` method

Comment: The `option.rect` is always relative to the viewport, you cannot use 0 based coordinates. Change that line to `QPoint(rect.x(), rect.center().y()), QPoint(rect.right()+1, rect.center().y())`.

Comment: im drawing custom items into the view. So i dont need the standard styleOptions. @musicamante works, thx m8.